# Run all the code in a Django ModelForm __init__() method after an invalid form submission

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

Based on this model:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    """
    Model Booking with foreign key to models Session and Bundle.
    """
    session = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name=_('Session'), to=Session, default=None, null=False, blank=False)
    bundle = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name=_('Bundle'), to=Bundle, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name=_('Price'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
                                default=None, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=100, default=None, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=_('Email'), null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Phone Number'), max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s @%s" % (self.name, self.bundle if self.bundle else self.session)
```

I have the following `ModelForm`:

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['session','bundle', 'name', 'email', 'phone_number']
        widgets = {
            'bundle': forms.RadioSelect,
            'session': forms.HiddenInput,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        session_pk = kwargs.pop('session', False)
        super(BookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if session_pk is not False:
            session = Session.objects.filter(pk=session_pk).first()
            if session:
                self.fields['session'].initial = session
            if not session or not session.is_bookable:
                raise Exception("Session is not available")
            elif session.bundles:
                self.fields['bundle'].widget.attrs['choices'] = session.bundles
                self.fields['bundle'].initial = session.bundles[0] if len(session.bundles) == 1 else None
                self.fields['bundle'].empty_label = None
            else:
                del self.fields['bundle']
```

Using this Class-based `CreateView`:

```
class BookingCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'events/booking_form.html'
    form_class = BookingForm

     def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """
        Extended method so we can pass in the Session object's pk. 
        """
        kwargs = super(BookingCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()

        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            session_kwarg = {
                'session': self.kwargs.get('pk', None),
            }
            kwargs.update(session_kwarg)
        return kwargs
```

I only want the bundle field to be displayed if the session field has associated bundles, as the code shows. It works when I first render the template. However if I post the form with invalid fields, the bundle field will be rendered along with the other fields.

**Question:** How can I make the logic inside my **init**() be executed after the form has been submitted incorrectly? Preferentially without having to recur to JavaScript.

Comment: You'll need to show your view. That code will be executed as long as the `session` value is not False or empty; are you passing it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've added the view. It seems `session` is only passed the first time the form is rendered because I'm removing it from `kwargs`. However I get a `TypeError` if I try to run it without removing `session`from `kwargs` and I don't know how to turn this around

Comment: Can you show the full message and traceback for that TypeError?

Comment: `TypeError at /en/django_events/book/1/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out how to solve my problem:

In my `ModelForm` I changed the signature of the `__init__` method to pass in my `session` value outside of the kwargs:

```
def __init__(self, session=None, *args, **kwargs):
    session_pk = session
    super(BookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then, in my `CreateView` method `get_form_kwargs(self)`, I was checking the condition:

```
if self.request.method == 'GET'
```

It happened that I wasn't passing any `session` in the form's kwargs when `request.method == 'POST'`. Problem solved!